# How can I call an async function from a getter in typescript

Tags: typescript, asynchronous, model

When deciding which calulation to perform to get a score back, I need to make an api call to check if an area is true or false. I can't make the getter async and am struggling to make required API call.

```
export class TopModel{

private isScoreInverted: boolean = false;

@computedFrom("probabilityIndex", "impactIndex")
public get score(): number | undefinded {   
     this.getRiskScoreInverted();
     if (this.isScoreInverted) {
        return Service.calculateInvertedScore();
    } else {
        return Service.calculateScore();
    }}

  constructor( data?) {
    if (data) {
        Object.assign(this, data);
    }
}

 private async getRiskScoreInverted() {
    const result = await this.matrixApi.getScoresInverted();
    return this.isScoreInverted = result;

    }
   }
```

`this.matrixApi.getScoresInverted()` returns true or false depening on the area we are currently in.

Comment: No that is not possible, mixing sync with async stuff always ends badly. You could try to get the value of scoreInverted cached. You can access the cache synchronously. But you need to implement a behavior to fill and maybe update the cache.

Comment: `I can't make the getter async`  Why?,  because it will have to be async if it calls any async code.